# Change Scaling via C#

Tags: c#, winapi, terminal, scaling, rdp

So we have this client using tssharp to connect to a remote computer via RDP. The client needs the scaling set to 125% for some reason. This makes the RDP-Session unusable, because tsplus takes the scaling from the system. So I want to habe a skript that switches the scaling from 125%->100%, then starts a .exe and then change the scaling back.
So here I am. My approach was to change the registry via C#. Personally I don't use Windows, so my knowledge is very basic. I can change the registry with my code. It works beautifully. I don't get the registry to reload though. I've tried to broadcast the update, but literally nothing was affected. Then I tried to kill and restart the desktopenvironment (i.e. Windows Explorer). The restart worked, but it didn't care about the new registry. Then I tried power something from microsoft, to automate the clicks. And that piece of s...oftware is absolutely unusable for that. So I'm out of ideas now... How can I make clicks in the Windowssystemsettings with c#? Is there any kind of library or something like this? I've tried the system32 api. Didn't work. Or do you have another idea on how to approach the problem? Like I said I pretty much know nothing about windows, so any idea is welcome. I literally just want to automate 8 clicks and I'm not able to do that.

Comment: "My approach was to change the registry via C#." - this is the wrong approach. Instead, launch whatever your RDP client process is with Windows' Application Compatibility shims such that you control that process' windows/GDI scaling.

Comment: Also, please clarify exactly what you mean by "scaling set to 125%" - because it's unclear if you're referring to local or remote desktop scaling, DWM scaling, monitor-based scaling, DPI vs. font-size-based scaling, and the myriad of other concepts in-between.

Comment: Furthermore, I can't find any information about any RDP client called "tssharp" - do you have a link to a repo or homepage for us to see?

Comment: @Dai: The software mentioned is [tsplus](https://tsplus.net/).

Comment: @AxelKemper You mean people _pay money_ for things we've been able to do for free for years?

Comment: I'll try the shims. Thank you. So I want to change the local scaling on the client. The RDP client TSplus (sry it was late, I fucked up) pulls the clients configuration and uses it for its scaling. But with 125% the right hand side of the screen is cut off. You can even give parameters to TS plus, but that's just for hight and weight, not for scaling. @AxelKemper thanks for clarifying it. And yes, seems so :D

Comment: @Dai Windows10 doesn't support shims anymore. If you mean rightclick and go for the  compatibility settings or the other settings for high dpi... I've tried that before even bothering writing a script. It doesn't work for some strange reason.

Comment: In case anyone has the same Problem: I wrote a Script with AutoHotKey. This is the v1. It does the job with hard coded Pixels and all the ugly stuff. I will upload the final Version as soon as I get there as well.

Comment: `send #r
sleep, 100
send ^a
send ^{Backspace}
send ms-settings:display
;sleep, 100
send {enter}
sleep, 1000
send #{up}
sleep, 300
click, 629, 665
sleep, 100
click, 629, 627
sleep, 100
run path\to\exe
sleep, 5000
click, 396, 89
sleep, 5000
send #r
sleep, 100
send ^a
send ^{Backspace}
send ms-settings:display
sleep, 100
send {enter}
sleep, 1000
send #{up}
sleep, 300
click, 618, 716
sleep, 100
click, 591, 754
sleep, 100
send !{F4}`

Comment: NavigiereZuSkalierung()
{
; öffnen der Anzeigeeinstellungen
    send #i
    sleep, 500
    send {tab}
    send {enter}
    sleep, 500

; Kommt bei Suchleiste raus. 5 Tabs bis Skalierung
loop, 5
{
    Send {Tab}
    sleep 50
}
}

RunterSkalieren(){
; Auswählen und Runterskalieren von 125 zu 100
    send {space}
    sleep, 100
    send {up}
    sleep, 100
    send {space} 
    sleep, 100
    send !{F4}
}

HochSkalieren(){
; scale 100 to 125
    send {space}
    sleep, 100
    send {down}
    sleep, 100
    send {space} 
    sleep, 100
    send !{F4}
}